# How can I convert this InstallScipt code to C#?

Tags: c#, installscript, installscript-msi

I'm converting my InstallScript Custom Actions To Managed Custom Actions using the DTF (Microsoft Deployment Foundation) Namespace. There is a piece of InstallScript code that I'm having trouble with converting to C# where I need to do some XML File manipulation. The original InstallScript Code is below. My code below it is how I've converted it so far. Is there a better way of converting it so that I can take advantage of the dot notation (Intellisense) instead of having the XML document object latebound.

```
    set oDoc = CoCreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    if (IsObject(oDoc)) then
        oDoc.async = FALSE;
        oDoc.validateOnParse = FALSE;
        oDoc.resolveExternals = FALSE;
        oDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = VARIANT_TRUE;

        oDoc.load(szCryptomaticConfigFile);

        szXPath = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_PATH;
        set oSettingsNode = oDoc.selectSingleNode(szXPath);

        szValue = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_VALUE;
        oSettingsNode.nodeTypedValue = szValue;

        oDoc.Save(szCryptomaticConfigFile);
   endif;
```

My Conversion

```
        dynamic oXMLDOMDoc = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.XMLDOM"));
        if (oXMLDOMDoc != null)
        {
            oXMLDOMDoc.async = false;
            oXMLDOMDoc.validateOnParse = false;
            oXMLDOMDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = VARIANT_TRUE;
            oXMLDOMDoc.load(szCryptomaticConfigFile);

            string szXPath = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_PATH;
            dynamic oSettingsNode = oXMLDOMDoc.selectSingleNode(szXPath);

            string szXValue = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_VALUE;
            oSettingsNode.nodeTypedValue = szXValue;

            oXMLDOMDoc.Save(szCryptomaticConfigFile);
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
```

Comment: You can (de)serialize XML to and from .NET objects using `XmlSerializer`.    You sometimes need to apply attributes to your classes to get exactly the XML you're after, but it's quite effective.

Comment: I doubt this would be the same working with my conversion from InstallScript (InstallShield Custom Actions) to .NET (C#).  But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Indeed it wouldn't - using `XmlDocument` as per the answers is far more appropriate here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is simply opening an [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), finding a specific node and updating its value before saving the file again.

The code is along the lines of (untested, typed from memory)

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(szCryptomaticConfigFile);
var node = xml.SelectSingleNode(szXPath);
node.Value = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_VALUE
xml.Save(szCryptomaticConfigFile);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was having trouble finding the same properties that were being used in the InstallScript code such as Async. ValidateOnParse, etc.  I did try adding a reference to Microsoft.MSXML and added a Using MSXML which allowed me to access the Async property, however the others were not there.

Comment: @Jamiec Ah Ha!  I think I found it. :) I need to use the DOMDocument class object in Microsoft.MSXML. Thank you. Your suggestions got me thinking.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield  I just tried to use the XMLDocument object and the properties I'm looking for are not there.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework's [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object gives you the same behavior as the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM objects, as described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973921.aspx).

In this case, your code would look something like this:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.PreserveWhiteSpace = true;
xml.Load(szCryptomaticConfigFile);

string szXPath = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_PATH;
var settingsNode = xml.selectSingleNode(szXPath);

string szXValue = CRYPTOMATIC_SETTINGS_VALUE;
settingsNode.InnerText = szXValue;

xml.Save(zzCryptomaticConfigFile);
```

One thing to note is that many of the load/save options are gone. These are no longer set on the top-level `XmlDocument`. Rather, those are settings on the `XmlTextReader` that is used to save and load the document. By default, the `Load()` method is synchronous and validating. Normally this is what you want.

However, if you XML contains DTD references that are off-site hosted and it takes a long time to resolve those DTD references. This is usually why `validateOnParse` gets turned off. If you need to do this, you need to use an overloaded `Load` method with your own reader. You can turn off the bit that resolves DTD references like this:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.XmlResolver = null;
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(szCryptomaticConfigFile, settings);
xml.Load(reader)
```